# exporting dataframe to tsv, but row.names are missing?

Tags: r, dataframe, export-to-tsv

```
b <- data.frame(var1 = c(9.2, 3.5,5.5), var2 = 1:3,row.names = c("a","b","c"))
write_tsv(b,path = result_path,na = "NA",append = T,col_names = T,quote_escape = "double")
```

b is exported as tsv but the row.names are missing. `row.names=T` is not an argument for write_tsv.
What can I do to maintain the rownames?

Answer (score 1):

Row names are never kept for any of the `readr` `write_delim()` functions.  You can either add the row names to the data or use `write.table()`.

Add row names:

```
library(tibble)

write_tsv(b %>% rownames_to_column(), path = result_path, na = "NA", append = T, col_names = T, quote_escape = "double")
```

Or:

```
write.table(b, result_path, na = "NA", append = TRUE, col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = TRUE)
```